# angular directive not working in jsp

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I need to add some angular directive in my JSP page but it's not working while working fine in HTML page.

Below is angular directive code:

```js
angular
  .module(
    name: 'xyz.app.directive', 
    requires:['xyz.services']
  ).directive(
    name: '**checkaccess**', 
    xyz.app.directives.ShowHideComponent.Factory()
  );
```

inside my JSP file:

```html
<li class="ng-hide" permission permission-only="::'xyz:employee:access-management:execute'" **checkaccess name="ACCESS"**>
```

could anyone help me on this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no valid answer, you should read about how to write custom directives -> **https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive**

Comment: custom directives are working fine in html files but not in jsp. What  I found is may be jsp is loading first before angular libraries for which this actually happens.Any idea on how to load angular libraries first instead of jsp??

Comment: JSP is executed serverside, AngularJS is a clientside framework ...